# distribution of values ​with for loop

Tags: c

This section does the electronic distribution. the results to be printed if the value of vNum is 32, will be `[O]2 6 10 12`
But I receive:

```
[O]2 6 10 12  
[P]  
[Q]
```

expected for 44 would be

```
[O]2 6 10 14  
[P]2 6 4
```

But I receive:

```
[O]2 6 10 14  
[P]2 6 4  
[Q]
```

Why are the P and Q levels being printed with no allocated values?
The aim was to appears only when there are values ​​in it, as in the case of 0 that nothing appears.
I know it's something in the outer for loop (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) that will run for each level. Starting with i equal to 3 (representing the O energy level) and going down to i representing the Q energy level. But I don't understand how to make the 3 not appear at once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        int vNum;

        printf("vNum: ");
        scanf("%d", & vNum);

        if (vNum > 0) {
            for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
                printf("[%c]", 82 - i);
                int limit = 2;
                int E = (limit <= vNum ? limit : vNum);

                for (int j = 0; j < i + 1 && E > 0; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", E);
                    usleep(50000);
                    vNum -= E;
                    E = (limit += 4) <= vNum ? limit : vNum;
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you do is what you get. So what is the problem? Do you do not understand yourself what  you are doing?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know it's something in the outer loop for `(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)` that will run for each level. Starting with i equal to 3 (representing the energy level O) and decreasing until i representing the energy level Q. But I don't understand how to make the 3 not appear at once.

Comment: @Cmistry Please [edit] your question and add this clarification to the question. I also suggest to change the code snippet into a [mre], i.e. allow us to copy&paste and compile and run the code.

Comment: @Bodo, done the minimal example reproducible. can you help?

Comment: I guess you did not compile the code. I get compilation errors.

Comment: @Bodo oops, it was an 'e' on the keyboard that I bumped into when I gave 4 space to the stackoverflow format. I formatted the question

Comment: The values are appearing because you have the line `printf("[%c]", 82 - i);` being executed unconditionally.  If you only want to print the header when there are some data to be printed, you cannot execute that line unconditionally.  (BTW, it ought to be `printf("[%c]", 'R' - i)` or similar; don't hard code the 82.)

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is compute E first and then do `if(E) { printf("[%c]", 'R' - i); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question prints the labels like `[Q]` in the outer loop when it is not yet clear if the inner loop will print anything.

There are different ways to print the label only if there are values to be printed.

One way is to move the `printf` into the inner loop and use a condition to print it only before the first value. In the example below, `c` contains the character to be printed, and it is set to 0 to skip the `printf` in subseqent inner loop cycles.

I also fixed a few problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        int vNum;

        printf("vNum: ");
        int rc = scanf("%d", & vNum);
        if(rc != 1) break;

        if (vNum > 0) {
            for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
                int c = 'R' - i;
                int limit = 2;
                int E = (limit <= vNum ? limit : vNum);

                for (int j = 0; j < i + 1 && E > 0; j++) {
                    if(c != 0) {
                        printf("[%c]", 82 - i);
                        c = 0;
                    }
                    printf("%d ", E);
                    usleep(50000);
                    vNum -= E;
                    E = (limit += 4) <= vNum ? limit : vNum;
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else break;

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```